# how to run script from user hdfs without password

Tags: permissions, rhel, sudo, sudoedit, hdfs

we create the following script on rhel 7.6

```
/home/run_tasks
```

and in visudo  we configured

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
hdfs ALL = (ALL) ALL
hdfs ALL= (root) NOPASSWD: /home/run_tasks
```

and

```
ls -ltr /home/run_tasks

-rwxrwxrwx  1 hdfs hdfs 6377 Sep 11  2019  /home/run_tasks
```

so when we run the script as

```
su hdfs -c "sudo /home/run_tasks"
```

we get

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

and after we marked the following lines ( from visudo )

```
#Defaults    requiretty
#Defaults   !visiblepw
```

we get

```
su hdfs -c "sudo /home/run_tasks"
ls: Permission denied: user=root, access=EXECUTE, inode="/../../..":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-x---
ls: Permission denied: user=root, access=EXECUTE, inode="/../../..":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-x---
```

Comment: You probably want `sudo -u hdfs ...`

Comment: when I run sudo -u hdfs /home/run_tasks   , still password is required , ( so what is missing here ? )

Comment: just want to mentioned that inside the script we have many hdfs cli's as - su -l hdfs -c " hdfs dfs -ls $folder "

Comment: You have a script that can be edited by anyone on the system, and can run as root?  This is extremely dangerous, it means anyone could change it or replace it with /bin/bash and have a root shell.

Comment: ok I will take care but how to solve the problem that still we have the password prompt ?